# Find tagged resources in Azure with Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

Does anyone know an easy way to find resources based on **multiple** tags? Eg find resources based on tag1 = 'value1' **and** tag2= 'value2'

The Find-AzureRmResource -Tag seems to ignore when multiple tags are specified in the hashtable, which means the following returns sesources with tag1 = 'value1' **or** tag2= 'value2, and sometimes just the one.

```
Find-AzureRmResource -Tag @{tag1 = 'value1';tag2 = 'value2}
```

Wondering if there is an easy query/copmmand for an **and** connector, or similar routine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I worked around it by using a query:

```
Get-AzureRmVM | where {$_.Tags['tag1'] -eq "value1" -and $_.Tags['tag2'] -eq "value2"}
```

I was only after VMs; I guess there is likely something similar for other resources.

Comment: I think you could substitute Get-AzureRmVm for Get-AzureRmResource to work with other types of resources. This is mostly a guess but I'm pretty confident it would work. Did you try your approach if multiple tags have identical values? Meaning "tag1:true" and "tag2:true" ?

Comment: Yep, Get-AzureRmResource will work in a similar manner as it also return Tags, but not in all instances. Eg "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions" resource types do not have Tags, so you'll get errors if you do not filter with these exceptions in mind.